# Faithful functor preserves monics

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

I've been trying to solve a problem and it all reduces to prove that not all faithfull functors preserves monomorphisms. But I haven't been able to come up with an example.
I was thinking about using the fact that $$f\in Hom(C) \text{ is monic}\iff f^{op}\in Hom(C^{op}) \text{ is epic}$$
Then if I have for example
$$f \in Hom(\textbf{Set}) \text{ s.t. } f \text{ is monic but not epic} \Rightarrow f^{op}\in Hom(\textbf{Set}^{op}) \text{ is epic but not monic}$$
So if I consider the functor that sends a category into its opposite then that would do the work.

Is my reasoning correct?
If not can you help me with an especific example?

Comment: The map $f \mapsto f$ from a category to its opposite is not a functor – it fails to respect domains and codomains.

Comment: Oh that's absolutely true, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: For an example that occurs naturally, you can consider the morphism $ℤ→ℚ$ in the category of rings. It is an epimorphism, but its image in $\mathbf{Set}$ by the forgetful functor is not an epimorphism. It is a classical example that you can keep in mind. An other example would be a dense subspace in the category of Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple counterexample to the claim that all faithful functors preserve mononmorphisms is to consider functors from the category $$\bullet\to\bullet$$ with only one non-identity arrow. The only non-trivial arrow is a monomorphism, but you can faithfully map it onto any non-monomorphism in any category.

Comment: Thanks I knew there was an elementary yet simple counter example